# Check if a value in a column exists in another column, if so, copy value from another column into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a csv file with columns [ID] [Number1] [Number2]

Now I would like to check if [Number1] exists in [Number2] and if so, I want to copy the value of [ID] into a new column [ID2].
I've tried with np.where [Number1] == [Number2] however this is not the output I want as this is checking row by row values. What I want the script to do is Check if [Number1]'s value exists in the entirety of [Number2].

So kind of like a for loop of some sort where row 1 of [Number1] is looped until the entirety of column [Number2] is finished and then it moves onto the next row. Meaning that if Row 1 of [Number1] is 50131 and row 5555 of [Number2] is 50131, then I want the [ID] from row 1 to be copied into row 5555 as [ID2].

If the value does not exist, I would like to print 'No Match' string in the row.

Input:

| ID | Number1 | Number2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9991 | 123 | 678 |
| 9992 | 321 | 321 |
| 9993 | 543 | 123 |
| 9994 | 678 | 543 |
| 9995 | 921 | 001 |

Expected Result: (when comparing Number1 to Number2)

| ID | Number1 | Number2 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9991 | 123 | 678 | 9994 |
| 9992 | 321 | 321 | 9992 |
| 9993 | 543 | 123 | 9991 |
| 9994 | 678 | 543 | 9993 |
| 9995 | 921 | 001 | 'NO MATCH' |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result with doing two merges. Once to get the `Number1` `ID`s where `Number2` matches and you merge those `ID`s with `Number2` to get the desired result.

```
connecting_ids = (df[['ID', 'Number1']]
          .merge(df[['Number2']], 
                 how='inner', 
                 left_on='Number1', 
                 right_on='Number2')
          .drop('Number1', axis=1)
          .rename(columns={'ID': 'ID2'})
)

(df.merge(connecting_ids, 
      how='left', 
      on='Number2')
  .fillna('NO MATCH')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following arrays:

```
ID = np.array([9991,9992,9993,9994,9995])
Number1 = np.array([123,321,543,678,921])
Number2 = np.array([678,321,123,543,1])
```

by using advanced indexing you can rearrange for the ID2:

```
filled = np.isin(Number2, Number1)
ID2 = np.full(np.shape(ID), 'No Match')

idx = np.where(Number1[None, :] == Number2[:, None])[1]
ID_arr = ID[idx]

ID2[filled] = ID_arr
```

which will get the following result for `ID2`:

```
['9994' '9992' '9991' '9993' 'No Match']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution , it is what im aiming for, however - excuse my beginner-ness but how would this translate if the data was actually in a single dataframe? I realised I forgot to point that out in my question.  When im trying to replicate by doing:

df['ID2'] = np.where(df['Number1'][None,:]==df['Number2'][:,None])[1]

Im getting an error:
Length of values (125) does not match length of index (200)

Comment: how would you make it so that if there was no match then that row value would become a string saying 'No Match' ?

Comment: @qnt13 The problem in the earlier answer was about the **string** that you mentioned. I have modified the answer to consider that. check it and let me know if there is any error.